# Am I causing statistical violations?

Tags: time-series, t-test

I am trying to analyze where the significant differences are between 2 sets of time series. Group 1 (Expert) has 29 trials normalised to 256 points whereas Group 2 (Novice) has 19 trials (see attached screenshot). Essentially I have carried out t-tests at each of the 256 time points and only plotted out (green plot) the data which is significant at p<=0.05.

Somewhere in the back of my head I think that I am introducing error by such repeated t-testing.

Can someone comment on whether or not this approach can be done?
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I can not think of any error that you are introducing, but then I am no expert. In my opinion you are just plotting results of many t-test in one graph.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "normalizing", what a "trial" is, and what a "time point" might be?  The lack of detail requires your readers to guess and make assumptions that might not be true. The resulting answers will only confuse and perhaps even mislead those who do not make the same guesses--which might include you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not correct for multiple comparisons then some of the significant differences are mere false positives. You can try the Bonferroni correction, which gives you a new critical level $$\alpha=\frac{0.05}{N} = \frac{0.05}{256}=0.0001.$$

Though, it is a conservative technique (may introduce false negatives).